# How to commit the binaries to svn?

Tags: svn, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to commit the binaries out of my C++ project, but the **debug** folder is always ignored.
Yes I know that isn't suggested to do that, but in my case it is required.

I have tried to add the folder with in the project settings or delete the patterns out of the ignored resources.
Also I have tried to use the context menu with *team* -> *add to version control*.
But all ways don't work for me.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: @Jeremy There is no error message, the selection for the files is always empty.

Comment: @Veger That doesn't work for me.

Comment: You tried it using the command line? Eclipse has a flag for 'derived' files. I believe Eclipse silently ignores you when you try to add such files...

Comment: Sorry, but I have no native installation of Subversion on my system.

Comment: Checkout the repository on another system (which has the svn binaries installed) and add the debug directory there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the [command line SVN client](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) and do:

```
svn add /path/to/debug
```

Comment: It is impossible, because the IT guidelines doesn't allow it.

Comment: What are the IT guidelines to which you refer? It's not a technical rule, so what are the constraints imposed upon you?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the files in an FTP site and write an rsync script to automatically sync the local directory after making the checkout from the SVN server.

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but I suppose it would work if the asker isn't allowed to add binary files to SVN for some arbitrarily imposed reason.